# How to check whether an os package is installed or not using php script

Tags: php, windows-8.1

If I am browsing my web application in windows 8.1 pro, I need to have a particular media package installed, I want to show some warning to users if the same is not present in the system. How can I check whether the package is installed using php script?

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the users Operating System using javascript with this command:

```
navigator.platform;
```

After getting this, display your warning

Comment: We already have script in place to find the Operating System, my question is how to check whether a package is installed or not in the OS using PHP  (for example media support package)

Comment: PHP is server-side, so that won't be possible, but you could build a java applet that will check if the required items are available